# Slide div up when user clicks anywhere on page

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I've seen a few answers for this solution, but can't seem to get any of them to work for me. I have a navigation nested in a div '#dashboard'. It slides up and down when a user clicks the open/ close div.

I'd like to have it slide back up and be hidden, when a user clicks anywhere on the page except the #dashboard div though.

This is what I have:

```
$('.open').on('click',function(){
   $('#dashboard').slideToggle();
});
```

I tried this (to no avail):

```
$('body').click(function() {
    $('#dashboard').slideUp();
});
```

Here's the markup:

```
<hgroup id="logo-menu">
<div id="dashboard">
    <nav role="navigation" id="main-nav" class="site-navigation main-navigation collapse navbar-collapse">
        <?php $walker = new Menu_With_Description; ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'walker' => $walker ) ); ?>
     </nav><!-- .site-navigation .main-navigation -->
</div> <!-- #dashboard -->

<a><div class="open"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/images/menu-down.png"></div></a>
</hgroup> <!-- .logo-menu -->
```

Wondering if someone might be kind enough to explain this to a noobie like me.

thanks!

Comment: is there a div covering the entire screen when it's open?

Comment: Nothing that's not always there, ie the body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the target element with event argument `e`:

**Update**

You can use [`e.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) to stop event bubbling from the dom, so your crack will be this:

```
$('.open').on('click',function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); 
   $('#dashboard').slideToggle();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
   if($(e.target).closest('div#dashboard').length == 0)
       $('#dashboard').slideUp();
});
```

When you click on link it will check the class name and when you click on any of the element of dashboard div it will check that the parent element of the clicked element dashboard exists in the dom or not.

### [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gr8L4/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Dhaval Marthak, when I add this block of code and then click the target that opens the dashboard div, it just slides down and then slides back up immediately. What other details should I provide about the dashboard div?

Comment: hmmm, still having the same issue with this. It just slides down and then slides back up immediately when clicked.

Comment: Can you provide me the HTML of both `.open` class and `#dashboard` div?

Comment: @EricBrockman Now you can check the answer, I'm sure you will glad ;)